# Save and load entire module as pickle

Tags: python, pickle, dill

So far I successfully managed to save my entire state with `dill`, but it causes some issues with other runtime variables. I'd like to just save a module that I use as my global variable container.

Googling this resulted in me only finding results about the dill module, and not how to store an entire module (or better the variables) from it.

So far i've tried to store the dict of the module, and then load it again. That caused an type error, and doesnt look like a convient way to handle this.

My "res"-module looks something like this:

```
VAR1="asd"
VAR2=123
```

My attempt:

```
import dill
import res

with open("test.pkl", 'wb') as pickle_file:
    dill.dump(res.__dict__,pickle_file)

res.VAR1="123"

with open("test.pkl", 'r') as pickle_file:
    res.__dict__ = dill.load(pickle_file)
```

Thank you very much!

Note: I choose this module approach, because I am accessing that module from several threads, and the information needs to be available and shared between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `dill` author.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you want to do, but is it something like this:

```
Python 3.6.15 (default, Sep  5 2021, 03:31:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> import res
>>> res.VAR1
'asd'
>>> res.VAR2
123
>>> 
>>> with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...   dill.dump(res, f)
... 
>>>
```

then in a new session... (note the 'rb' in the load):

```
Python 3.6.15 (default, Sep  5 2021, 03:31:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('test.pkl', 'rb') as f:
...   res = dill.load(f)
... 
>>> res
<module 'res' from './res.py'>
>>> res.VAR1
'asd'
>>> res.VAR2
123
>>>
```